# WordPress API POST request in Python returns "401 Client Error: Unauthorized" with Nginx

Tags: python, php, wordpress, api, nginx

I'm working on a Python script that interacts with the WordPress REST API to create posts programmatically. However, when I make a POST request to the WordPress API endpoint, I consistently receive a "401 Client Error: Unauthorized" response. My WordPress site is running on Nginx, and I suspect there might be a configuration issue causing this problem.

Here are the relevant details:

I'm using the requests library in Python to send the POST request to the WordPress API.
The WordPress site is hosted on an Nginx server.
The API endpoint I'm trying to access is https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts.
I have confirmed that the API endpoint is valid and accessible by testing it with other tools like cURL and Postman.
I have included the necessary headers in the request, such as the Content-Type and Authorization headers.
The authentication mechanism I'm using for the WordPress API is a token-based authentication plugin.
Despite including the required headers and valid authentication credentials, I consistently get the "401 Client Error: Unauthorized" response. I suspect some misconfiguration in my Nginx setup might be causing the issue.

Here are a few things I've checked/tried:

I verified that the authentication credentials I'm using are correct.
I checked the Nginx access and error logs but found no relevant error messages.
I reviewed my Nginx configuration files, including the server block and any relevant location blocks, but couldn't identify any obvious issues.
I'm hoping someone can provide some insights into why I'm encountering this "401 Client Error: Unauthorized" response when making the POST request to the WordPress API. Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on troubleshooting and resolving this issue within the context of Nginx.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I appreciate any help you can provide.

```py
import json
import requests
from colorama import Fore
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
def create_post(title, content, site):
    """
    """
    url = f"https://{site}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
    post = {
        "title": title,
        "status": "publish",
        "content": f"{content}",
        "categories": 2,
        "post_type": "question",
        "slug": generate_slug(title),
        "date": "2022-02-17T10:00:00",
    }
    print(HTTPBasicAuth('test', 'test'))
    response = requests.post(
        url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('test', 'testtest'), json=post
    )

    if response.status_code == 201:
        print(
            Fore.GREEN
            + f"Post Published Successfully : {response.json()['link']}"
            + Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX
        )
        return response.json()
    response.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Have you checked https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#why-is-authentication-not-working already?